# No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call: navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, flutter-test

I'm trying to mock AutoRouteObserver() class to test navigiations in my project, but when I user the mocked instance in the navigatorObservers parameter I have the following Error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MissingStubError was thrown building AutoRouteNavigator(state:
_AutoRouteNavigatorState#0b446):
'navigator'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
navigator

Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the mock for
MockNavigationHistoryObserver with 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true'.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  AutoRouteNavigator
```

here is my code:

```
 void main() async {
  var authManagerMock = getAndRegisterAuthManagerMock();
  var mockRepository = getAndRegisterRepositoryMock();
  final _appRouter = AppRouterAutoRoute(authGuard: AuthGuard());
  var mockAutoRouterObserver = MockAutoRouteObserver();

  Widget makeTestableWidget() {
    when(authManagerMock.isLoggedIn()).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => false);
    return MaterialApp.router(
        routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate(_appRouter, navigatorObservers: () => [mockAutoRouterObserver]),
        routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser());
  }
testWidgets('Tapping forgot password text', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget());
    await tester.pump();
    Finder forgetPasswordButtonFinder = find.byKey(Key('forget-password-button'));
    expect(find.byKey(Key('forget-password-button')), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.tap(forgetPasswordButtonFinder);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byKey(Key('forget-password-button')), findsNothing);
    expect(find.byKey(Key('submit')), findsOneWidget);
    verify(mockAutoRouterObserver.didPush(any, any));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure Mockito can find the relevant mocks. This is how I did. First, add the MockSpec to your @GenerateMocks or @GeneratorNiceMocks code, with a symbol like this

```
@GenerateNiceMocks([
  MockSpec<AuthService>(),
  // ...
  MockSpec<MockRouter>(as: Symbol('MockAppRouter'))
])
```

Then define the Mock and the implementations we need to get it to mock for us

```
// workaround to get Mockito to generate StackRouter mocks
class MockRouter extends Mock implements AppRouter, StackRouter {}
```

Then run the build_runner from a shell to have mockito generate your mocks.

```
dart run build_runner build
```

This should auto generate a huge amount of mocking code that looks similar to this:

```
class MockAppRouter extends _i1.Mock implements _i37.MockRouter {
  @override
  List<_i8.AutoRoute> get routes => (super.noSuchMethod(
        Invocation.getter(#routes),
        returnValue: <_i8.AutoRoute>[],
        returnValueForMissingStub: <_i8.AutoRoute>[],
      ) as List<_i8.AutoRoute>);
  @override
  _i8.RouteType get defaultRouteType => (super.noSuchMethod(
  ...
```

Then in your test, verify your appRouter calls like this. We're using get_it to swap out the real implementation of appRouter with the mock implementation, but there's various ways of doing this.

```
verify(appRouter.push(SignUpViewRoute())).called(1);
```